# Install wowza Media server on my webserver

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, wowza

i was installed wowza media server on my local pc (Ubuntu 13.04). and i was streamed correctly. but now i want to install wowza media server on my web server (linux). please tell any one how to install this media server on my hosting webserver and how to streaming there

Answer (score 0):

Installing Wowza Media Server on your web server will be very similar to what you have already done on your local PC. If you plan to do HTTP adaptive streaming (Apple HLS, Adobe HDS, Microsoft Smooth Streaming, or MPEG DASH) from Wowza, then you just need to make sure that you do not run into a port 80 conflict with your web server. You would do this by either specifying a different HTTP port for Wowza (e.g., port 8080), or better yet, by using a separate IP address on the Web server for Wowza and then still using port 80 for both the web server and Wowza to ensure your content flows across most firewalls.

If you need more detailed help, just send email to support@wowza.com. Someone usually replies within a day.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

There is a script that installs the Wowza automatically. It works well for Centos OS, I don't know about Ubuntu support. Check this tutorial in this [link](http://help.cianetbrazil.com.br/knowledgebase.php?article=69)!, it may help you. At least, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://blog.xentoo.info/2012/05/16/wowza-3-ubuntu-12-04-setup/). It guides you through the basic setup process. I recommend you install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which is going to be supported till 2017. Also install open-ssh server, Apache2 web server, MySQL web server and PHP.